# React Native: what is a proper way to pass style as props, when using spread operator on the child component

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my *component A:*

```
const GenericTextInput = (props) => {
  return (
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        {...props}
      />
  );
};
```

This is my *component B:*

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
   return (
      <View>
        <GenericTextInput
                    placeholder="Email"
                    autoFocus={true}
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    returnKeyType="next"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    placeholderTextColor='rgba(250,248,244, .4)'
                    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(250,248,244, .7)'
        />

        <GenericTextInput
                    placeholder="Password"
                    placeholderTextColor='rgba(250,248,244, .4)'
                    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(250,248,244, .7)'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
        />
    </View>
   );
};
```

I want to add a specific styling to the 2nd `GenericTextInput` in my *component B*. In the *component A* I want to use the `spread operator` (it is so convenient).

If I simply make:

```
//component A

const GenericTextInput = (props) => {
  return (
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.input, props.styles]}
        {...props}
      />
  );
};


//component B

    const SignIn = (props) => {
       return (
          <View>
            <GenericTextInput
                        placeholder="Email"
                        autoFocus={true}
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        returnKeyType="next"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        placeholderTextColor='rgba(250,248,244, .4)'
                        underlineColorAndroid='rgba(250,248,244, .7)'
            />

            <GenericTextInput
                        placeholder="Password"
                        placeholderTextColor='rgba(250,248,244, .4)'
                        underlineColorAndroid='rgba(250,248,244, .7)'
                        secureTextEntry={true}

                        style={styles.customStyleForSecondInput}
            />
        </View>
       );
    };
```

I'll have 2 `style` `props` in *comp. A*, and the second `style` `prop` will **completely** overwrite the first one.

What is the proper way of adding a specific styling to the 2nd `GenericTextInput`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I usually destructure the named property (`style`) out for the object, and use the rest operator to collect the remaining props into a new object:

```js
const {style, ...rest} = props;

return (
  <TextInput
    style={[styles.input, style]}
    {...rest}
  />
)
```

Note that this requires the [transform-object-rest-spread](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread) Babel plugin. This plugin is included in the React Native Babel preset, so it will work out of the box -- but may not work in other JavaScript environments without this plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that destructuring like this is possible: {foo, ...bar} = obj

Comment: @Edgar I added a bit more details about this syntax, for posterity.

Comment: what if the style prop is an array?

Answer (score 5):

If you want your custom styles to completely overwrite the preset ones, I believe you can do something like

```
style={props.style || styles.input}
```

but I think you're asking how to have the custom styles overwrite some of the preset ones. In that case it would be

```
style={[styles.input, props.style]}
```

since you're passing the property down as 'style' not 'styles' you just drop the s at the end.