# How do I pass style props to a custom React Native component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

With many library components I see that you can do something like

```
<Component style={{// some styling}} />
```

and those styles will be applied to the component, even if that component is comprised of multiple other components (for example, the Calendar component from react-native-calendars). How can I apply this type of styling to a custom component of mine?

This is what I have right now, but I would like to be able to pass a style tag that can be used to change the height of the view inside the Modal:

```
  export default function Backsheet({isVisible, setIsVisible, children}) {
  const toggleBacksheet = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        backdropColor="#000000"
        backdropOpacity={0.2}
        transparent={true}
        animationIn={'fadeIn'}
        isVisible={true}
        onBackdropPress={() => toggleBacksheet()}
        animationOut={'fadeOut'}>
        <View style={styles.container}>{children}</View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just pass the style prop through to the component you want it on: `style={props.style}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: what is a proper way to pass style as props, when using spread operator on the child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665370/react-native-what-is-a-proper-way-to-pass-style-as-props-when-using-spread-ope)